# How do i rollback operation if first two operations completes successfully but third transaction fails to complete

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, gmail

I am developing .net application where in three operations are to be performed at one go. At first, record is to be inserted into table(I am calling stored procedure to insert record into table), then first mail is to be send to admin and second mail is to be send to user who fills form.. I am not sure as to how can these three operations can be performed successfully. If first two operations are completed and last operation is not able to complete, then it must rollback. I am thinking of using transaction to do so and roll back using try catch exception if any of the operation is not complete. But my doubt is if record is inserted and first mail is send and mail send failure occurs in second mail send, is the first mail send rollbacked !!! is there another method to do so???

Comment: Maybe you should cosider sending your emails outside of the transaction scope by using events?

Comment: can you tell me which event will enable me to do so because i am new to it? also how can i handle concurrency.. What if record is inserted but email send failure occurs??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's always a better separation of concern if you can separate different kinds of logic into a more modular approach. A database operation should not be dependent on email sending operations, different modules for different purposes, also have a look at dependency injection for ease of testability.

Anyway, if I've understood your question correctly I beleive you want something like this?:

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);

public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public enum EventTypes
    {
        Success,
        Error
    }

    public CustomEventArgs(string s, EventTypes type)
    {
        msg = s;
        this.type = type;
    }
    private readonly string msg;

    public string Message
    {
        get { return msg; }
    }

    private readonly EventTypes type;

    public EventTypes Type
    {
        get { return type; }
    }
}

public class TransactionManager
{
    public event CustomEventHandler CustomEvent;

    public void PerformTransaction()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                //Perform your workload

                scope.Complete();

            }

            if (CustomEvent != null)
                CustomEvent(this,
                    new CustomEventArgs("Transaction performed successfully message",
                        CustomEventArgs.EventTypes.Success));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (CustomEvent != null)
                CustomEvent(this,
                    new CustomEventArgs(exception.Message, CustomEventArgs.EventTypes.Error));                
        }
    }

}

public class Engine
{

    public void PerformWorkload()
    {
        var tm = new TransactionManager();

        tm.CustomEvent += transaction_CustomEvent;

        tm.PerformTransaction();

    }

    private void transaction_CustomEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        //Simulate send operation successful mail
        switch (e.Type)
        {
            case CustomEventArgs.EventTypes.Error:
                //Send error mail
                break;
            case CustomEventArgs.EventTypes.Success:
                //Send success email
                break;
        }
    }
}
```